# How to return an imported module in node.js within a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, authentication

I'm a creating a node.js single page app. I want to show a specific view in homepage if user is authenticated. For this purpose, I created a function to check if user is auth. It works fine.

However, when I want to return a specific view, I get some problems with this.

I have tried a few different approaches, but I cannot return any view.

**views**

```
const notAuth = require('../view1')
const isAuth = require('../view2')
```

This was my first attempt:

```
const home = function (ctx) {
  if (ctx.auth) {
    return isAuth
  } else {
    return notAuth
  }
}
module.exports = home
```

Then, I tried to use `module.exports` only:

```
module.exports = function home (ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.auth) {
    return isAuth
  } else {
    return notAuth
  }
  next()
}
```

And finally, I tried this:

```
const authenticated = function (ctx) {
  if (ctx.auth) {
    return isAuth
  } else {
    return notAuth
  }
}

module.exports = function home (ctx, next) {
  return authenticated(ctx)
  next()
}
```

**Note:**

Each module I required with a specific view works fine if I use for example:

```
module.exports = notAuth
```

How can I return a specific imported module within a function?

Comment: Each one of your examples should be exporting a function. However, you haven't said how they are failing. Just curious what the method signature of the functions exported by `view1` and `view2` From the symptoms you describe, I am thinking they differ from `func(ctx,next)`

Comment: You're not showing how you are using the exported function. Any of the above would work but it depends on how you call them

Comment: @barry-johnson They were not failing, at least I couldnt see how. I didn't get an error.

Comment: @slebetman Thanks. Actually Thai was right. I needed to pass the context on target route.

Comment: Yes, the problem was you needed to invoke a function. It had nothing to do with the exports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to actually pass the context on to the target route

```
const home = function (ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.auth) {
    return isAuth(ctx, next)
  } else {
    return notAuth(ctx, next)
  }
}
```

Comment: Great. It works great with the context on target route. Thanks a lot.